# Magento custom menu module not showing

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have installed [Magento custom menu module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/responsive-custom-menu.html), but I cannot get it to resolve on my site. I have followed the checklist in the docs and everything seems fine, including the following lines in my layout page.xml, which calls the nav. Anyone come across this or know what's going on?

```
<block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml">
     <block type="page/html_topmenu_renderer" name="catalog.topnav.renderer" template="page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml"/>
</block>
```

When I look in the console, I can see the navigation section, but the div is empty and I am getting nothing in the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Magento connect installs the files into the RWD folder by default. If, like me, you use a custom theme - copy

> skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/webandpeople/

to your theme folder.

Hope this helps others.